# How do I utilize the index for my callback?

Tags: javascript, indexing, callback

Going through some practice problems and can't figure out how correctly callback. It returns "

```js
let myForEach = function(array, cb) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    cb(array[j])
  }
};

myForEach(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(el, i) {
  console.log(el + ' is at index ' + i);
});


// expected return "a is at index 1"
// actual return "a is at index undefined"
```

I tried to call i as an extra argument, and tried to use this.i, call it within the scope of the cb, all either return undefined or are ignored.

Comment: `cb(array[j])` — If you want the second parameter to get a value then you need to pass a second argument when you call the function. It won't come from nowhere.

Comment: You are calling your function (cb) with one parameter (array[j]) but are expecting it to be called with 2 when you call the function (the value and the index). You need to pass the index as the second parameter to cb.

Comment: Oh, this makes total sense. I was confusing i in the callback with an automatic indexer. Thanks y'all.